# How to change the log4j2 properties

Tags: java, unix, testng, log4j2

while running my test cases in unix enivornment which are supported by testng framework ,I want to change the log level of  log4j2 properties file through the command  line.Is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JVM property `log4j.configuration` to specify custom log4j configuration file, e.g.:

```
java -jar .... -Dlog4j.configuration=/home/log4j.properties
```

That file should contains specific setting for Unit tests

Comment: Means I need to maintain more than one log4j2.properties files?

Comment: @Praveen yes. Or you can change log level in `@BeforeClass` block

Comment: According to the apache [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration), you set the `-Dlog4j.configurationFile` system property to specify your properties file in log4j2